# Edit configuration page opens when I "run" android project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Why I am not able to run an android project while it syncs properly and I have defined the sdk version? Still I get `Please select android sdk` and "edit configuration" window opens.

[image]

As you can see, API 27 is installed.

[image]

Comment: Check Buid Variants, is it in release?

Comment: @mTak: The "Edit Build Types..." in Build menu is disabled

Comment: Click Build Variants on the down left edge of AS, above Favorites

Comment: Which android studio version you are using?

Comment: @adityakamble49: Android is 3.1.2

Comment: @mTak: The build variant is "debug".

Comment: I think it would be better to update to AS 3.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **SDK Location** in your **local.properties** file as below

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Aditya\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

If correct location already present. Try following options

- Add that SDK location to user environment variable ANDROID_HOME
- **Sync** gradle with project files
- Clean and **Rebuild** Android Project
- Close Android Project, Remove project name from list, restart android studio and add project again and **Sync and rebuild project**

**Edit 1**

- Try with File -> **Invalidate Caches** -> Invalidate,
- Delete **.gradle** and **.idea** folder in Project
- Delete **.AndroidStudio3.1** folder from Home directory [take backup if you want]

  Then close project from Android Studio, and Remove project from List.
  Try to start again

Comment: There is no `.AndroidStudio3.1`. I did All other steps. It is now working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issues with Android Studio 3.1.x, especially when using Gradle Kotlin DSL. I recommend you to:

1. Remove project from Android Studio left menu. Just press cross.
   [image]
2. Close Android studio
3. Re-import project.

If this won't help try to use Android Studio 3.2 Beta, its more stable. If this won't help either try to remove caches or re-clone project.

Answer (score 0):

I did : Android Studio -> File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files and it works